# Is there a way in C# to unify smaller objects into larger ones (think TypeScript union type)?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'd like to be able to merge types together without making all the classes by hand. Below is a contrived example of what I'm looking for.  Here we have three types `Person`, `PersonMeta`, `PersonDetails` and I would be looking for generation of `FullPerson`.
This is similar to the type union in TypeScript.

```cs
public class Person
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class PersonDetails
{
   public string MiddleName { get; set; }
}

public class PersonMeta
{
   public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Expected:

```cs
// e.g generated
public class FullPerson
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public string MiddleName { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What would be the point? Or to ask another way, why not just get rid of `Person`, `PersonDetails`, and `PersonMeta`, and just go with `FullPerson`?

Comment: The real examples are much, much larger and only portions of the data is needed in some scenarios.

Comment: Can you consider interfaces? - That what can be consider as alternative to union types

Comment: Notice that typing is not slowest bottleneck of programming, but reading is ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can not (see my BUT below) inherit multiple classes directly in C#, but you can do a simple inherit:

```
public class FullPerson : Person
{
   public string MiddleName { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
public class Person
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class PersonDetails : Person
{
   public string MiddleName { get; set; }
}

    public class FullPerson : PersonDetails 
    {
       public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

BUT you can inherit multiple interfaces. A little more complicated, I give you a tutorial because is not an answer to your question, but can helps:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Huj3Jbz-NFw

**UPDATE**

**IF** you are working with json and you don't want "write" the classes of a json you already have, you can use this tool:

https://json2csharp.com/